# Open document version as a binary

Tags: version-history

I’m trying to open a document version as a binary but keep getting an exception. I have no problem opening the item as a binary:

```
$binary=$spweb.GetFile($item.url).OpenBinary()
```

However when I try the same thing with a version:

```
$versionbinary=$spweb.GetFile($version.url).OpenBinary()
```

It bombs out with:

> Exception calling "OpenBinary" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot open file "_vti_history/512/Documents/Test4.docx"."
>
> At line:13 char:55
>
> - $binary=$spweb.GetFile($ver.url).OpenBinary <<<< ()
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException##

I've reached a dead end. Is there another way to open a document
version as a binary?

Answer (score 1):

Get it from File’s versions, not from Item’s version

```
$_fileVersions = $_item.File.Versions;
$_fileVersion = $_fileVersions.GetVersionFromLabel(“1.0”);
$_binary = $_fileVersion.OpenBinary();
```

Check [here](http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/backup-documents-from-document-library-with-powershell-script/) one example of PowerShell script for backup of documents.